# Room library - how is the DAO interface intertwined with the Database?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, annotations, android-room

I am currently working through a study book that utilizes the Room library for accessing a SQLite database on Android.

In this book, the database class is created as follows:

```
@Database(entities = {WorkTime.class}, version = 1)
public abstract class WorkTimeDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
    public abstract WorkTimeDao workTimeDato();
```

I am really confused by the method that is declared in this class. What does it do? The method body is not declared anywhere. I know that abstract methods do not need to be defined, they are abstract, which basically means they function as an interface. But I am calling this function from my mainActivity:

```
getApp().getDb().workTimeDato().add(workTime);
```

`getApp().getDb()` returns an instance of WorkTimeDatabase-class. But what does `workTimeDato()` do?

I think that this is related to Room and not to the specific example I am going through in my book. That's why I post this question here.

Can it be that somehow this `workTimeDato()` method is related to the WorkTimeDao interface that I had to create? It must be, because I am not implementing this interface anywhere. I have just annotated this interface with `@Dao`.

Can somebody explain to me what is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am really confused by the method that is declared in this class. What does it do?

It will return an instance of a `WorkTimeDao` object. Given how Room is set up, `WorkTimeDao` should be a `@Dao`-annotated type (`interface` or `abstract class`).

> Can it be that somehow this workTimeDato() method is related to the WorkTimeDao interface that I had to create?

Yes. If you look at the return type of `workTimeDato()`, it returns an instance of `WorkTimeDao`.

Room will code-generate a class that implements `WorkTimeDao`, and it will code-generate a class that implements `WorkTimeDatabase`. Those code-generated classes will work with the API that you have described (e.g., the methods declared on `WorkTimeDao`) and the Room requirements that you have tied to those (e.g., executing the queries from `@Query`-annotated methods on your `@Dao`).

At runtime, when you use `RoomDatabase.Builder` to get access to your database, while you will reference it using the abstract types that you wrote, the underlying objects will be from these code-generated classes.

You will find the source to the code-generated classes in your module's `build/` directory. For a Kotlin project, they would be in `build/generated/source/kapt/`. For a Java project like yours, they would be in `build/generated/source/apt/`.

Comment: does the Room-library know that it needs to create a Dao object and return it just from the return type of the method?

Comment: @Luk: Presumably, yes.